# TL-Schema - how to get access_hash of private channel?

Tags: ssl, telegram, tls1.2, telethon

To send messages (messages.sendMessage), you need `channel_id` and `access_hash`. For any public channels or chats, I can get it using `contacts.resolveUsername` and pass the `username`. But what about private channels, Is it accessible only by link? I Can't find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: if you use client.send_message you can just pass the link directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it either by joining the channel and checking the retval or iterating your dialogs (client.iter_dialogs)